# How to pass FXML ComboBox instance from one controller to another?

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, javafx, combobox

I have a JavaFX app I am making. I am having difficulty passing a combobox instance from one screen to another. My ComboBox variable is called reportBox. It is defined in home.fxml and injected into MyController.java. When I attempt to switch screens in MyController, I am creating a ReportScene Object (class I made) and passing the ComboBox in the constructor of Report Scene. Report Scene is also loading report.fxml.

While playing around with the code to make this work, I'll either get an error when attempting to set the items of reportScenebox or I will get no error but the Combobox will be empty (so it seems it is not getting the passed reference). Ultimately, I shouldn't have to directly set the items of reportscene box if I say that reportSceneBox = MyController.SceneBox. The error I sometime get depending on the iteration of the code is: ReportScene.reportBox = MyController.ReportBox, I get "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException".

I don't understand why this error is occurring or why reportSceneBox is not properly being populated/copied from Mycontroller.reportbox. Can someone help explain or help with a solution to this issue? Thank you.

MyController.java

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;


public class MyController {

    private final static String[] REPORT_TYPES = {"Sales Report", "Inventory Report", "Guacamole Metrics"};


    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> reportBox;

    private ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(REPORT_TYPES);


    public static final String[] getReportTypes()
    {
        return REPORT_TYPES;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        //initialized drop down of report types
        reportBox.setItems(items);

        //Handles reportBox event
        reportBox.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            String inputReport = reportBox.getValue();
            int reportIndex = indexOf(inputReport); //is do while loop here useful for input validation. it might not be, but something to consider. 
            if( reportIndex > -1)
            {
                System.out.println(reportIndex);
                ReportScene rs = new ReportScene(reportIndex, this.reportBox);
                //MATCH FOUND, create report scene;
            }
            else
            {
                // NO MATCH FOUND. NEED NEW INPUT.
            }
            // if input is valid, create new Report Scene of given REPORT_TYPE
            System.out.println(reportBox.getValue());
        });


    }

    private int indexOf(String reportType)
    {
        int index = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < REPORT_TYPES.length; i++)
        {
            if(reportType.equalsIgnoreCase(REPORT_TYPES[i]))
            {
                index = i;
                i = REPORT_TYPES.length + 2;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
```

Home.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import java.lang.String?>


<VBox prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MyController">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open…" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Recent" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Revert" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preferences…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undo" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Redo" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cut" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unselect All" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About Report Generator" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" id="pane">
      <children>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="271.0" layoutY="26.0" style="&#10;" text="" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#9f9f9f" wrapText="false">
          <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
          </font>
        </Label>
            <!-- <DatePicker layoutX="390.0" layoutY="44.0" />
            <DatePicker layoutX="189.0" layoutY="44.0" />
            <MenuButton layoutX="43.0" layoutY="44.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="MenuButton">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sales Report 1" onAction="#processReport1" fx:id="menuItem1"/>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Inventory Report 1" />
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="InOut Report 1" />
              </items>
            </MenuButton> -->
            <Button layoutX="43.0" layoutY="317.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Run" />
            <ComboBox layoutX="43.0" layoutY="44.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Select a Report" fx:id="reportBox" editable="True" >
              <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">

                </FXCollections>
              </items>
            </ComboBox>
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

ReportScene.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;



public class ReportScene {

    private int reportIndex;
    private final String[] reportTypes = MyController.getReportTypes();
    private Scene reportScene;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> reportSceneBox;
    private Button homeBtn;

    private final double[] reportWidths = new double[reportTypes.length];
    private final double[] reportHeights = new double[reportTypes.length];


    public ReportScene()
    {
        System.out.println("Default constructor for report scene");
    }

    public ReportScene(int reportIndex, ComboBox<String> reportBox)
    {
        //reportTypes = MyController.REPORT_TYPES;//getReportTypes();
        //destroy old scene and generate new one
        //destroy old scene here

        this.reportIndex = reportIndex;
        this.reportSceneBox = reportBox;
        //ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(MyController.getReportTypes());

        //this.reportSceneBox.setItems(items);
        //this.reportBox.setVisible(true);
        //this.homeBtn = new Button
        Arrays.fill(reportWidths, Main.getHomeWidth());
        Arrays.fill(reportHeights, Main.getHomeHeight());
        this.generateScene();
    }

    //@FXML
    public void generateScene()
    {
        try
        {
            Parent newRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Reports/" + reportTypes[this.reportIndex] + ".fxml"));
            //newRoot.getChildrenUnmodifiable().add(this.reportBox);
            //newRoot.getParent().get

            Stage stageInstance = Main.getPrimaryStage();
//          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
//          ComboBox<String> ap = (ComboBox<String>) newRoot;
//          ap.getChildren().add(this.reportBox);
//          ap.setLayoutY(-580.0);
//          this.reportBox.setVisible(true);
            this.reportScene = new Scene(newRoot,reportWidths[this.reportIndex],reportHeights[this.reportIndex]);
            //this.reportScene.
            reportScene.getStylesheets().addAll(this.getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            stageInstance.setScene(this.reportScene);
            stageInstance.show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

report.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import java.lang.String?>

<VBox prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ReportScene">
  <children>
    <MenuBar VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="New" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open…" />
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Open Recent" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save As…" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Revert" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Preferences…" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Quit" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undo" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Redo" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cut" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Copy" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Paste" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Select All" />
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Unselect All" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About MyHelloApp" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
    <AnchorPane id="pane" maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
        <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="384.0" layoutY="28.0" style="&#10;" text="Sales Report" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#9f9f9f" wrapText="false">
          <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
          </font>
        </Label>
            <DatePicker layoutX="229.0" layoutY="91.0" />
            <DatePicker layoutX="464.0" layoutY="91.0" />
            <Label layoutX="229.0" layoutY="67.0" text="Start Date" />
            <Label layoutX="464.0" layoutY="67.0" text="End Date" />
            <Button fx:id="Run" layoutX="49.0" layoutY="496.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="49.0" text="Run" />
            <ComboBox layoutX="43.0" layoutY="44.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Select a Report" fx:id="reportSceneBox" editable="True" >
              <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                </FXCollections>
              </items>
            </ComboBox>
            <!--  <Button fx:id="Home" layoutX="49.0" layoutY="41.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Home" /> -->
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Quick side note: you should **not** be passing an actual `Node` from one controller to another. This is very strange behavior and goes against many programming conventions. Instead, you should create a new `ComboBox` in your next scene or just retrieve the **data** to populate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combobox that you pass to your constructor is "overwritten" when you create `newRoot` in your `generateScene()` method. You create your `newRoot` and then use that as the view for the new scene that you're showing--that's why your combobox is empty.